# Excel - Filtering spreadsheet 'A' based on information from spreadsheet 'B'

Tags: excel, filtering

I have 2 spreadsheets.

1. list of customers and addresses
2. list of sales reps and their respective territories, which are determined by zip codes

Is it possible to filter the first spreadsheet using the data from the second spreadsheet?

*The goal here is to take the customer list for the state of Texas for example and show only the customers in certain zip codes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a named range to the zip codes in the second sheet. Then use a formula like this (replace `G1` with whatever is appropriate for the column in the first sheet your zip codes are in):

```
=if(countif(ZipRange,G1)>0,"YES!","NOPE!")
```

Now, you have a Yes/No value that you can use to filter on using Excel's built in filtering tool.

I'm out.